# How to download an image correctly, flutter/iOS

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I have a function that download an image from URL, for android, works fine, but ios, doesn't, because ios change the `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory` every time that recompile.

Here's the following code:

```
Future<String> downloadAndSaveImage(String imageUrl) async {
    try {
        var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(imageUrl));

        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
            Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
            const uuid = Uuid();
            final nomeAleatorio = uuid.v4();
        
            String filePath = '${directory.path}/$nomeAleatorio.png';
            File file = File(filePath);
            await file.writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes);
            print('Imagem salva com sucesso em: $filePath');
            return filePath;
        } else {
            print('Falha ao fazer o download da imagem: ${response.statusCode}');
            return '';
        }
    } catch (e) {
        print('Erro ao fazer o download da imagem: $e');
        return '';
    }
}
```

How can I resolve that?